# jquery on end of concurrent animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

So I'm running two concurrent animations on an element and i want to do something AFTER both animations have ended

```
        $("#MyDiv").stop().animate({left: "-=" + 500 + "px"}, 1000);
        $("#MyDiv").animate({top: "-=" + 500 + "px"}, 1000, 

function() {
//do something here
});
```

so this is my approach. I was wondering if there is a better approach, because the first animation may end a few milliseconds earlier or later.

**second question: is there any difference between .stop().animate() and .animate() ? If yes, what is it ?**

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "because the first animation may end a few milliseconds earlier or later"

No, you have set both animations to 1000ms.

> "is there any difference between .stop().animate() and .animate() ? If yes, what is it ?"

Yes, if the animation is active and stop() is called, the first animation will be stopped.

Since you are animating the same element, you dont need to select it twice. I suggest you do something like this:

```
$("#MyDiv").stop(true).animate({left: "-=" + 500 + "px", top: "-=" + 500 + "px"}, 1000, 
function(){
    //animation complete
});
```

If the animation gets "stuck" you can add a second bool to the stop method, `stop(true, true)` ("jumpToEnd"). The first one will clear the animation queue. Hard to say what you need without seing more code.

Comment: i know that i have set them to 1000ms, but i measured the exact timing and always is 1010 ~ 1014 ms. that's why i asked

Comment: Nice solution. @MIrrorMirror it's "impossible" to make it run after exactly 1000ms, which is why you should use a callback function instead (which Johan's answer does).

Comment: @MIrrorMirror Ok. If you want to fine-tune the jquery callback and isn't satisfied with the time it fires you can always add your measured millisecond in a `setTimeout`-function inside the animation complete callback. But AFAIK, the callback should trigger at the right time.

Comment: @MIrrorMirror Timers are only exact to a certain precision. It doesn't help using the measured delay either, since [the error is (most of the time) normally distributed](http://ejohn.org/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/). Some timers with a very small delay (around 10 ms) might even run immediately without any delay at all. The real question is: does it really matter?

Comment: the settimeout won't be necessary due to the fusion you suggested. i just noticed that with 2 animations, one ended slightly before the other. thanks alot!

Comment: i'm noticing a weird behaviour ( even without the fusion, just the first animation, moving the div to the left ), if i set it to 30 seconds, it's very fast in the beginning and very slow in the end

Comment: @MIrrorMirror The animation should be linear by default. But you can always double check it. It can be passed in as a string (third parameter).